# django signals with bulk delete/update

Tags: django, signals

I can't find any documentation on why does this happen, but according to the docs bulk operations should not trigger models signals.

Now the issue is this, if i do somequeryset.delete()a signal is triggered for each deleted object even if it is a bulk operation!
On the other hand, somequeryset.update(someField=5) will NOT trigger any signal!

So this is pretty much an unexpected result, I would hope for both to behave the same.

Django 1.7.7

Any ideas? I want deletes to have a signal but triggering it on bulk deletes is not acceptable

Comment: `somequeryset.delete()` is calling `delete` method, it is not a bulk.

Comment: No it is not, as I have checked the queries made, and it does a DELETE ... WHERE id IN ( list of ids that matched the query)

Comment: After that it seems to call the post delete events, but without actually doing any delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#delete) it really doesn't call delete() method on each item but it DOES calls signals. I don't know if that is possible but I also agree that there should be at least some option en queryset.delete() to skip signals execution.

Comment: You are right, the delete operation really needs some tweaking. What if I just want a bulk delete option, always using the "first path" rather than calling signals and such. Seems like right now the only option would be a raw query.

Comment: Apparently, [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9519) is a long standing open ticket related to this feature. you are right, raw query seems the only option right now :-( The automatic detection for fast-path works if you have no `pre_delete` or `post_delete` defined but skipping signal is not optional yet

Comment: I found a work around to get similar behavior. I just removed the post_delete signal and put that code on a custom ```delete()``` method. this way, when you erase one object (```object.delete()```) then the code originally in the signal is executed but when you do QuerySet.delete(), as it doesn't call object.delete() you get ride of that code.